# Multiplicação de matrizes C++

Tags: c++

Estou a fazer um programa em C++ que permita a multiplicaçao de 2 matrizes, o meu problema é que eu nao queria ter de predefinir o tamanho de cada matriz, entao utilizei o seguinte codigo:

```
    int ia, ib, ja, jb, ic, jc;
    float matriz_A[ia] [ja], matriz_B[ib][jb], matriz_C[ic][jc];

    printf("Escolheu input por TECLADO");
    printf("\n==========================");
    printf("\n\nLeitura de dados");
    printf("\n===================");
    printf("\n\nIndique o tipo de matriz que pretende inserir ['i' e 'j']");
```

porem o codigo contem erros, como é que posso corrigir o problema?

Objectivo:
Fazer o utilizador escolher o 'i' e o 'j' de cada matriz.
O queria que a matriz C tivesse a dimensao ic e jc de acordo com a matriz A e B
Obrigado desde ja.

Answer (score 1):

No primeiro ponto, vocês está usando o valor das variáveis `ia, ib, ja, jb, ic, jc` antes de povoá-las. Então, elas possuem apenas lixo e o seu programa tem comportamento errático.

Se você realmente deseja testar o programa, inicialmente eu recomendo fortemente que você não comece com a interface no meio dos testes. O que eu quero dizer com isso? Deixe-me explicar melhor na parágrafo abaixo.

Até agora, você mostrou 7 linhas de código, sendo que duas são apenas declarações de variáveis e as outras 5 são mensagens de interface. Dessas 7 linhas, pode-se dizer que apenas as 2 de declaração de variáveis são referentes ao teu objetivo, mas também não te trazem para mais perto dele. Veja, você ainda nem começou a multiplicação de matrizes! Ainda está povoando os dados pela interface!

Deixe para fazer a interface num momento posterior, foque logo no seu problema real e, depois de ele estar resolvido, você pode se preocupar com uma interface para receber dados.